# iterator issues

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

In the arrayList I customize the iterator and then use sort of stl and the iterator to sort string (words).

```
   **//arrayList.h**
template<class T>
class arrayList {
public:
    // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    arrayList(int initialCapacity = 10);
    arrayList(const arrayList<T>&);
    ~arrayList() {
        delete[] element;
    }

    // ADT methods
    bool empty() const {
        return listSize == 0;
    }
    int size() const {
        return listSize;
    }
    T& get(int theIndex) const;
    int indexOf(const T& theElement) const;
    void erase(int theIndex);
    void insert(int theIndex, const T& theElement);
    void output(ostream& out) const;

    // additional method
    int capacity() const {
        return arrayLength;
    }
    void reverse();

    // iterators to start and end of list
    class Pointer;
    Pointer begin() {
        return Pointer(element);
    }
    Pointer end() {
        return Pointer(element + listSize);
    }

    // iterator for arrayList
          class iterator
          {
             public:
                // typedefs required by C++ for a bidirectional iterator
                typedef bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
                typedef T value_type;
                typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
                typedef T* pointer;
                typedef T& reference;

                // constructor
                iterator(T* thePosition = 0) {position = thePosition;}

                // dereferencing operators
                T& operator*() const {return *position;}
                T* operator->() const {return position;}

                // increment
                iterator& operator++()   // preincrement
                          {++position; return *this;}
                iterator operator++(int) // postincrement
                          {iterator old = *this;
                           ++position;
                           return old;
                          }

                // decrement
                iterator& operator--()   // predecrement
                          {--position; return *this;}
                iterator operator--(int) // postdecrement
                          {iterator old = *this;
                           --position;
                           return old;
                          }

                // equality testing
                bool operator!=(const typename arrayList<T>::iterator right) const
                      {return position != right.position;}
                bool operator==(const typename arrayList<T>::iterator right) const
                      {return position == right.position;}
             protected:
                T* position;
          };  // end of iterator class


    //      class Pointer: public arrayList<T>::iterator {

    class Pointer:public arrayList<T>::iterator{

    public:
        typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T* pointer;
        typedef T& reference;
        // constructor
        Pointer(T *thePosition) {
            position = thePosition;
        }

        Pointer(const Pointer & rhs)
        {
            Pointer(rhs.position);
        }
        //arithmetic operators
        Pointer operator+(int n) const;
        Pointer & operator+=(int n) ;
        Pointer operator-(int n) const ;
        Pointer & operator-=(int n) ;
        reference operator[](difference_type& n)const ;
        bool operator<(const Pointer &rhs) const ;
        bool operator<=(const Pointer & rhs) const;
        bool operator >(const Pointer & rhs) const;
        bool operator >=(const Pointer &rhs) const ;
        int operator -(Pointer rhs) ;

        T operator*() const ;
        T* operator->() const;

        // increment
        Pointer& operator++() ;
        Pointer operator++(int) ;

        // decrement
        Pointer& operator--() ;
        Pointer operator--(int) ;

        // equality testing
        bool operator!=(const Pointer right) const;
        bool operator==(const Pointer right) const;
    protected:
        T* position;
    };




protected:
    T* element; // 1D array to hold list elements
    int arrayLength; // capacity of the 1D array
    int listSize; // number of elements in list
};



**// main.cpp**

int main() {
     .....
    sort(dict.begin(),dict.end(),compare_nocase);/////// error
      ....
    return 0;
}
```

The errors are :

```
    c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:138:7:   instantiated from 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer, _ForwardIterator2 = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer]'
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:111:6:   instantiated from 'void std::__move_median_first(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Compare) [with _Iterator = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer, _Compare = bool (*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)]'
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2260:7:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer, _Compare = bool (*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)]'
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2302:62:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer, _Size = int, _Compare = bool (*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)]'
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::Pointer, _Compare = bool (*)(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)]'
..\hw3prob2.cpp:53:45:   instantiated from here
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:101:11: error: no matching function for call to 'swap(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)'
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:106:5: note: candidates are: void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>]
c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2564:5: note:                 void std::swap(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

I check for several hours but have no ideas. Thank you for any help.

**`Edit`**

Finally, it works. Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Is there more context on that error message?  If so, can we see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer` does not satisfy the requirements of a random access iterator.  At a glance, `operator*` should return the type `reference`, not `T`.  And it should have a default constructor.

Edit: Also, this constructor doesn't initialize the constructed object.

```
seamlessPointer(const seamlessPointer & rhs)
{
    seamlessPointer(rhs.position);
}
```

It constructs a temporary anonymous `seamlessPointer` and then forgets about it.  You want something like

```
seamlessPointer(const seamlessPointer & rhs)
    : position(rhs.position)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that the `operator*` function has the wrong return type.  Right now it's

```
T operator*() const
```

When it should be

```
T& operator*() const
```

Currently, you return a *copy* of the values you're iterating over, so when `std::sort` internally calls `std::swap` to try to exchange the values, it will be passing in copies of the array elements rather than the actual array elements themselves (more technically, rvalues instead of lvalues).  Changing the return type to `T&` means that you return the lvalue, which can indeed be swapped.

Try changing this and see if it fixes anything.