# iterator problem

Tags: c++, iterator

The code is as follows

```
template<class T>
class arrayList {
public:
    // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    arrayList(int initialCapacity = 10);
    arrayList(const arrayList<T>&);
    ~arrayList() {
        delete[] element;
    }

    class seamlessPointer;
    seamlessPointer begin() {
        return seamlessPointer(element);
    }
    seamlessPointer end() {
        return seamlessPointer(element + listSize);
    }

    // iterator for arrayList
      class iterator
      {
         public:
            // typedefs required by C++ for a bidirectional iterator
            typedef bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            typedef T* pointer;
            typedef T& reference;

            // constructor
            iterator(T* thePosition = 0) {position = thePosition;}

            // dereferencing operators
            T& operator*() const {return *position;}
            T* operator->() const {return position;}

            // increment
            iterator& operator++();
                      {++position; return *this;}
            iterator operator++(int);

            // decrement
            iterator& operator--();
            iterator operator--(int) ;

            // equality testing
            bool operator!=(const iterator right) ;
            bool operator==(const iterator right) ;
         protected:
            T* position;
      };  // end of iterator class

        class seamlessPointer: public arrayList<T>::iterator {

        public:
            typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
            typedef T* pointer;
            typedef T& reference;
            // constructor
            seamlessPointer(T *thePosition);
            seamlessPointer(const seamlessPointer & rhs);
            //arithmetic operators
            seamlessPointer operator+(int n) ;

            seamlessPointer operator-(int n) ;
    };

protected:
    T* element; // 1D array to hold list elements
    int arrayLength; // capacity of the 1D array
    int listSize; // number of elements in list
};

c:\wascana\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4: error: no match for 'operator-' in '__last - __first'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iterator problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882241/iterator-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over your code it appears that you've got the right kinds of ideas by including those typedefs with your own iterator implementation.  However, why go to all the trouble in the first place when something else could do it for you?  Have you looked at [iterator_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/) or the standard [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/)?  They just add typedefs to your code which will aid you in developing new iterator types.

Comment: @Sean you're right.  Removed that from my answer, although, now my answer isn't much of an answer anymore.

Comment: @Sean great to hear but did my answer really help you solve your issue?  What ultimately was the cause of the problem?

Comment: @ wheaties, actually, I do not know the exact reason. I copy and paste again from the original code and it suddenly works. Probably it is typo? Anyway, I should thank you for your new ideas.